# How can I get a mysql script that works in PHPmyadmin, to work in a PHP mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

Simple question with i'm sure a simple answer. I have searched around and can't find a solution. Basically my code below works in Phpmyadmin but it wont work in a PHP mysql query script. The code orders my "rank" row by the largest number, and then updates the "position" row with a number, starting at 1 for the greatest number in the "rank" column, and then incrementing the "position" row as the "rank" row values become smaller.

```
SET @r=0;
UPDATE Data SET position= @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY rank DESC;
SET @r=0;
SELECT *, @r:= (@r+1) as position FROM Data ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you explain how does it not work? Maybe show us the PHP code with any errors if possible?

Comment: Yes 
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect(blah blah blah blah);
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SET @r=0;
UPDATE Data SET position= @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY rank DESC;
SET @r=0;
SELECT *, @r:= (@r+1) as position FROM Data ORDER BY rank DESC;") ; 
 
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); 
?>


error is "Invalid query: "

Comment: `mysqli_query()` is only for one SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple queries here. Try using [mysqli_multi_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php):

```
$result = mysqli_multi_query($con,"SET @r=0; 
              UPDATE Data SET position= @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY rank DESC;
              SET @r=0; SELECT *, @r:= (@r+1) as position 
              FROM Data ORDER BY rank DESC;") ;
```